# Login to WepApi from Windows Phone App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i have created a WebAPI, using out-of-the-box security from the MVC5 template in VS2013.

When i try to obtain a Token with the use of Fiddler using a Post to

```
https://localhost:44300/token
```

and providing the Content of: username=bob&password=bob&grant_type=Password i'll get a token back.

In my WP8.1 app, i have the following function:

```
 internal async Task<string> GetBearerToken(string siteUrl, string Username, string Password)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(App.BaseUri); 

            var response = client.PostAsync("Token", new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password, Encoding.UTF8)).Result;
```

When calling this function from my WP8.1 app, the Response is like:

```
StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Length: 0
}
```

the response.RequestMessage.RequestUri reads:

```
https://localhost:44300/Token
```

Why cant the App find this resource?
(BTW the webserver is running)

Paul

Comment: You cannot use `localhost` outside you dev machine. Try with LAN IP and also your mobile should be connected to that LAN network. BTW how are you testing your mobile app Simulator or direct deployment to phone?

Comment: Testing with the Simulator, and a normal non-securecd API-call gets results back from the localhost...

Comment: Have you tried with LAN IP?

Comment: Yep did that, no results. Whilst im Simulator, i can also start the Internet Explorer of Windows Phone 8.1 and from there i can browse to my localhost:44300 and see my MVC "Homepage"

Comment: When using the non-ssl variant, it is working... must be some Firewall Setting...